# How to observe ContentProvider changes for coroutine flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-contentprovider, kotlin-flow

I have a flow to fetch data from database via content provider.

```
fun getDataFlow(): Flow<Result> {
    return flow {
      emit(Result.Loading)

      // fetchAll() is the method to fetch data via contentResolover.query()
      val results = fetchAll()
      emit(Result.Success(categories))
    }.catch { e ->
      emit(Result.Error(e))
    }
  }
```

So how to trigger refetching data when ContentProvider data changed (onChange get called)?

```
val contentObserver = object : ContentObserver(null) {
      override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
        super.onChange(selfChange)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use callback flow

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun ContentResolver.register(uri: Uri) = callbackFlow<Boolean> {
    val observer = object : ContentObserver(null) {
        override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
            trySend(selfChange)
        }
    }
    registerContentObserver(uri, false, observer)
    
    invokeOnClose { 
        unregisterContentObserver(observer)
    }
}
```

then u can do something like this

```
getDataFlow().combine(ContentResolver.register("YOUR_URI")){data, isSelfChange -> 

}
```

Here I have written an **article** on medium.com which explains how you can use kotlin Flow with **MediaStore/ContentResolver**.

**Article**
https://medium.com/@sheikhzakirahmad/kotlin-flow-contentresolver-and-mediastore-the-key-to-effortless-media-access-in-android-fad56db16fdd

You can find whole code here.
https://github.com/prime-zs/Audiofy2

Comment: It works, but how can we use it to register not only changes, but simulate obtaining the result (like initial value in flow) in "onResume" method to trigger all this "value X is SUCH now" logic?

Comment: I mean, your method have an issue if app was collapsed and settings was changed. App will not gain any "value changed" knowledge from flow like this

Comment: I didn't understand what you are saying. Can you please elaborate.